# java.lang.Class and java.lang.Object

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance

Ok conceptual difficulty here - Reading and learning Java from a book

It mentions the following (over the course of explaining several different subjects) -

1. Java does not support multiple inheritance in the class hierarchy. So if class C is a child class of class A, then it cant also be a child class of class B (I know interfaces have a solution to offer here)
2. `java.lang.Object` is the primordial class that all classes (system and user) 'extend'. So every class is a direct or indirect child of the class `java.lang.Object`
3. classes in Java are not just compiler artefacts - but at run time, are represented by the instances of the class `java.lang.Class`

Doesn't #3 mean classes defined in the language themselves are of type `java.lang.Class` - while #2 means they are also of type `java.lang.Object` - contradicting #1 ? like which class are java classes children to?

And if #1 still holds, I am guessing it would mean that #3 is just saying the "runtime representation" of classes are instances of the class `java.lang.Class` - which is a child of `java.lang.Object`??, but the classes themselves are children to `java.lang.Object`??

Your guidance is appreciated!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're confusing *class* and *instance* of a class.  A *class* is an instance of the class `Class`, and `Class`, like all classes, is a subclass of `Object`.  An instance of, say, `String` is not an instance of `Class`, nor is it a subclass of `Class`.  It's just that the `String` class itself is an instance of `Class` (and not an instance of `String`).

Comment: (To really blow your mind, consider that the class `Class` itself is an instance of `Class`, and, furthermore, the class `Object` is also an instance of `Class`.)

Comment: (Oh, `Class<Class> clazz = Class.class` works. Now I'm really confused.)

Answer (score 2):

> Doesn't #3 mean classes defined in the language themselves are of type `java.lang.Class`

No. `(Class) testclass` is syntax error - No classes are subclasses of `java.lang.Class` - It's `final`.

`Class` extends `Object` and represents a `class`.

Let's say I have `TestClass` which extends `Object` by default, now `TestClass.class` or `(TestClass).getClass()` exists - they return `Class<TestClass>`, which extends `Object` and is an instance of `Class`.

[But if you look into the Java documentation for `Class`, you'll see they are more than `Object`s.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)

Comment: Thanks!  I get it now - it just seems a bit odd to think Class is a subtype of Object - but once I wrap my head around that it does make sense

Answer (score 2):

> 3) classes in Java are not just compiler artifacts - but at run time, are represented by the instances of the class java.lang.Class

That is correct.

> Doesn't #3 mean classes defined in the language themselves are of type java.lang.Class

That is correct.

> while #2 means they are also of type java.lang.Object

That is correct.

> ... contradicting #1 ?

That is incorrect.  There is no contradiction.

The "extends" relationship is defined ONLY between classes ... and between the `Class` objects that represent the classes at runtime.  If you look at the `java.lang.Class` API you will see methods such as `Class getSuperclass()` and `isAssignableFrom(Class)` ... though `isAssignableFrom` is testing the "subtype" relationship.  Note that these methods take another Class as an argument, or return another Class.

There is no "inherits" or "extends" relationship between classes and instances.  And there is no such relationship between the runtime objects either.  The fact that `java.lang.Class` extends `java.lang.Object` is not relevant here.

---

> And if #1 still holds, I am guessing it would mean that #3 is just saying the "runtime representation" of classes are instances of the class java.lang.Class - which is a child of java.lang.Object?

That is correct.

> .... but the classes themselves are children to java.lang.Object?

That is also correct.

However the thing to note is that these two properties don't directly follow from each other.  It is (sort of) coincidental that there are similar-looking relationships between classes and the runtime classes that represent classes.

Answer (score 1):

> *3) classes in Java are not just compiler artifacts - but at run time, are represented by the instances of the class java.lang.Class*

This is not correct. Java objects are *objects*. They also have an *attribute* that represents their class type.

```
public class Test  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
      String s = "x";
      Class cls = s.getClass();
      System.out.println("s=" + s.toString());
      System.out.println("cls=" + cls.toString());  
   }
}
```

Output:

```
s=x
cls=class java.lang.String
```

It's confusing that we say "Java objects are classes". These is true in the general sense, but with this specific technical detail, it's inaccurate.

Loosely speaking, Java objects are stored in `*.class` files, which is something else that makes this distinction confusing.

Comment: Would it be less confusing if they were stored in `*.object` files?

Comment: @HotLicks I don't understand. Is that a joke?

Comment: @HotLicks Well I'm not getting it. Are you suggesting something could be improved in my answer?

Comment: Actually, I think `*.class` stores a Java `class`, `anonymous class`, or an `inner class`. Java objects are stored in the heap unless serialized.

Comment: No.  Just playing with words.  As @Unihedron suggests, if it were `.object` then it would be even more confusing.

Comment: @Unihedron When nothing is executing, Java objects are stored in class files. When executing, they're loaded into memory.

Comment: @HotLicks It is very low "class" to make me the "object" of your joke.  ;)

Comment: What can I say?  I'm an old assembler guy at heart -- no class at all.

Comment: The OP doesn't say that "objects are classes" - I'm not sure whose argument you are trying to rebut? What makes you think that "Java objects are also stored in *.class" files? AFAIK Java objects only exist in memory, unless you count serialized representations.

Comment: Very loosely speaking (which I've added to my answer), Java objects are stored in class files. Yes, it's not technically, specifically, exactly accurate, but I challenge you to explain to a Java newbie--as the OP admits to being--the distinction between "a fully-realized object constructed in memory during runtime" and "a class file that holds the byte code of a classfile, which is *really* a representation of its source-code file, which is a very specific *slice* of an object". I think the explaination is appropriate given the context, and I definitely don't think it deserves a downvote.